# using dynamic arrays in web app using php

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, codeigniter

My website is dependent on unique content provided by the user's input.

So they type in, "sports," they will receive content based on sports.  That is simple enough.  However, once I start adding more keywords to it, it gets a bit more complicated, at least in the way I'm doing it.

I need to start constantly checking whether the user inputted data is an array or not, and manipulate the data different.

I am currently storing the user's selection using Codeigniter's session class, then retrieving and manipulating the data based on its value.

So they submit the form and my JS runs:

```
$('#topics_form').submit(function() {
    var topic = document.getElementById('topics_filter').value
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ajax/update_session_topic',
        dataType: 'json', 
        data: { topic: topic },
            success: function(){
                load_custom_topics()
            }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Then update_session_topic runs in my AJAX model

```
public function update_session_topic()
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('active_topic') == FALSE) 
    {
        $array['active_topic'] = $this->input->post('topic');
        $this->session->set_userdata($array);
        return true;
    } else {
        $this->page_model->add_session_topic($this->input->post('topic'));
        return true;
    }
}
```

When theres only 1 value, its no big deal.

However, when trying to add a second value...I am forced to check whether its an array or not, or make it one.

```
    public function add_session_topic($current_filter)
    {
        $session = $this->session->userdata('active_topic');
        if (is_array($session) == false)
        {
            $session = array($this->session->userdata('active_topic'));
        } 
        foreach ($session as $keyword)
        {
            if ($keyword == $current_filter)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        $session[] = $current_filter;
        $active['active_topic'] = $session;
        $this->session->set_userdata($active);
        return true;
    }
```

This occurs in my views as well.

Its kind of annoying, and I was hoping there was a better way to do this.  Im still new to PHP/codeigniter, so I am open to anything.

Thanks!

Comment: If i were you i would always work as if it were an array. you can simple cast like `(array) $session` and if its an array it will be left alone, or it will be converted to an array like `array($session)` if it isnt. Theres no reason to check as long as the only possible types it can be are a string or an array. Then just only have logic for working with an array.

Comment: i was trying to do that, but my concern is that when I pull from the session->userdata, and if there was already an array, it would create another multidimensional array on top of it.  Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: It will casting an array to an array does nothing.

Comment: im not familiar with the term casting ... would you mind detailing it a bit? I did a quick search but no good explanations appeared.

Comment: [Casting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) is when you force something to a sepcific type (string, object, array, etc..). its done by putting the type in parentheses before the variable: `$arr = (array) $thevariable`